# Copy a dataframe from one Global Environment to another

Tags: r, dataframe

I have lots of dataframe in my project and I need to use one of them for another project. Is there a simple way to copy a dataframe and paste to another project in R?

Comment: You can use `save()` and `load()`. Please read the documentation of the functions.

Comment: You can also use `dput()` or `dump()` to get a text representation that can by copy/pasted.